# How to copy and paste from Windows to ubuntu 18.04 on VMware

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

When I was running Ubuntu 16.04 as a guest of Windows 10 in VMware PlayreI was able to copy text or files from Windows to Ubuntu and vice versa. After upgrading Ubuntu 18.04, copying and pasting from one to another no longer works. Moreover any usb or external drive is not seen by Ubuntu. On the Player menu, on Removable devices there is an option to "connect(disconnect from host)". Choosing that option does not give any error. But within a few seconds, it gives the same option.
I have tried to mount manually, and from several posts, doing:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

gives

```
Disk /dev/sda: 360 GiB, 386547056640 bytes, 754974720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2142f293

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 750782463 750780416  358G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       750784510 754972671   4188162    2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       750784512 754972671   4188160    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

From the above, I do not know which partition to mount.

Comment: You need to reinstall vmware tools.

Comment: Thanks @Ribeiro, I have reinstalled VMware Tools. Behaviour is the same, so am guessing there is no solution to my problem. Thanks for your time.